# Strapi. Server wasn't able to start properly

Tags: strapi

I created new tables in the admin panel, but soon the project closed and there were a lot of errors in the console -
[

```
2022-08-09 10:17:22.950] debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2022-08-09 10:17:22.951] error: CREATE TABLE `_knex_temp_alter937` (`id` varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `a` varchar(255) NULL, `created_at` datetime NULL, `updated_at` datetime NULL, `published_at` datetime NULL, `created_by_id` integer NULL, `updated_by_id` integer NULL, `type` varchar(255) NULL, `sn` bigint NULL, CONSTRAINT `modems_created_by_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by_id`) REFERENCES `admin_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL, CONSTRAINT `modems_updated_by_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by_id`) REFERENCES `admin_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL, CONSTRAINT `modems_created_by_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by_id`) REFERENCES `admin_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL, CONSTRAINT `modems_updated_by_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by_id`) REFERENCES `admin_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL) - AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
SqliteError: CREATE TABLE `_knex_temp_alter937` (`id` varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `a` varchar(255) NULL, `created_at` datetime NULL, `updated_at` datetime NULL, `published_at` datetime NULL, `created_by_id` integer NULL, `updated_by_id` integer NULL, `type` varchar(255) NULL, `sn` bigint NULL, CONSTRAINT `modems_created_by_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by_id`) REFERENCES `admin_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL, CONSTRAINT `modems_updated_by_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by_id`) REFERENCES `admin_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL, CONSTRAINT `modems_created_by_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by_id`) REFERENCES `admin_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL, CONSTRAINT `modems_updated_by_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by_id`) REFERENCES `admin_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL) - AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
    at Database.prepare (/home/daniil/counter/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/methods/wrappers.js:5:21)
    at Client_BetterSQLite3._query (/home/daniil/counter/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/better-sqlite3/index.js:30:34)
    at executeQuery (/home/daniil/counter/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/internal/query-executioner.js:37:17)
    at Client_BetterSQLite3.query (/home/daniil/counter/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:146:12)
    at /home/daniil/counter/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/transaction.js:363:24
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Client_BetterSQLite3.trxClient.query (/home/daniil/counter/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/transaction.js:358:12)
    at Runner.query (/home/daniil/counter/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/runner.js:130:36)
    at Runner.queryArray (/home/daniil/counter/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/runner.js:224:21)
    at Runner.queryArray (/home/daniil/counter/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/runner.js:276:31)
```

Please help how to solve this problem? Restarting the project doesn't help.